# how to transfer the mtime from one file to another

Tags: unix, terminal, filemtime

I'm using `exifautotran` to automatically reorient images imported from a camera.  This script uses `jpegtran` to do the rotations, and this utility is not able to modify the original file.  I need to preserve the mtime because I'm then matching the media to missions completed in our app based on the timestamp.

**Basically I just need to access the mtime from one file and assign it to another**

How can I do this in a Mac UNIX terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [touch](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch) with the -r flag to set timestamps relative to another file. Use -m to change only the mtime.

`touch -m -r /path/to/old/file /path/to/new/file`